# What does Ward mean in early US Census Records?

Tags: united-states, census-records

I've noticed on some of the early censuses that when giving the address you will see something like "Ward 5" or "Ward 7". Is that something like Districts?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to. This is an earlier Q&A that may be of interest to you: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3386/is-city-ward-information-provided-in-u-s-census-records-useful

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  We already have another question about using Ward information shown in census records, so I've marked your question as a duplicate.  I hope the answers there will be helpful.  Do investigate the individual wards in the city you're studying -- you can find out all sorts of interesting things that way.